# Handling a class that contains derivations of the same class which are required to behave differently

Tags: c#, polymorphism, derived-class

I have a Command class that, when executed, performs a command on a IScriptable object

```
[
    XmlInclude(typeof(CommandPositionSettings)),
]
public abstract class CommandSettings
{
    public List<Command> Parameters = new List<Command>(4);

    public abstract Command Load();
}

public abstract class Command
{
    public List<Command> Parameters = new List<Command>(4);

    public Command(CommandSettings settings) 
    {
        Parameters = settings.Parameters;
    }

    public abstract void Execute(IScriptable scriptableObject);
    public abstract int GetArgumentCount();
    public abstract CommandSettings Write();
}
```

This works well for certain commands such as Position

```
public class CommandPosition : Command
{
    public CommandPosition(CommandPositionSettings settings)
        :base(settings = settings == null ? new CommandPositionSettings() : settings)
    {
        if (settings == null)
        {
            settings = new CommandPositionSettings();
        }
    }

    public override void Execute(IScriptable scriptableObject)
    {
        Vector3 position = new Vector3();
        position.X = Parameters[0].Execute();
        position.Y = Parameters[1].Execute();
        position.Z = Parameters[2].Execute();

        scriptableObject.Position = position;
    }

    public override int GetArgumentCount()
    {
        return 3;
    }

    public override CommandSettings Write()
    {
        CommandPositionSettings settings = new CommandPositionSettings();

        settings.Parameters.AddRange(Parameters);

        return settings;
    }
}
```

until I try to execute a different type of command that only needs to return a value instead of requiring an IScriptable.  In the above code this would be where the X, Y and Z values are obtained for the position.

At this point it would be fine to store each parameter as a float but sometimes I wish to do something a bit more involved than return a value.  For example randomise between two values each time the Command is executed.

```
public class CommandRandom : Command
{
    public CommandRandom(CommandRandomSettings settings)
        : base(settings = settings == null ? new CommandRandomSettings() : settings)
    {
        if (settings == null)
        {
            settings = new CommandRandomSettings();
        }
    }

    public override float Execute()
    {
        return ToolBox.Random.NextFloat(Parameters[0], Parameters[1]);
    }

    public override int GetArgumentCount()
    {
        return 2;
    }

    public override CommandSettings Write()
    {
        CommandPositionSettings settings = new CommandPositionSettings();

        settings.Parameters.AddRange(Parameters);

        return settings;
    }
}
```

This command is only required to return a random floating point number and not directly affect the IScriptable object.

Another reason why I am currently deriving them from the same class is that when a command line string is interpreted it creates a new Command for each matching form of *Command(para0, para1...paraN)*.

A Command can also be nested inside another Command.

So *Command(para0, para1...paraN)* where: para1 = *Command(para0, para1...paraN)*

How then can I distinguish between a nested Command that is only required to return a value and one that directly affects the IScriptable object itself?

Answer (score 0):

You could solve it using generic types like:

```
public interface IScriptable
{
    Vector3 Position;
}

public abstract class CommandSettings<T>
{
    public List<Command<T>> Parameters = new List<Command<T>>(4);

    public abstract Command<T> Load();
}

public class CommandRandomSettings : CommandSettings<float>
{
    public Command<float> Load()
    {
        return null;
    }
}

public class CommandPositionSettings : CommandSettings<object>
{
    public Command<object> Load()
    {
        return null;
    }
}

public abstract class Command<T>
{
    public List<Command<T>> Parameters = new List<Command<T>>(4);

    public Command(CommandSettings<T> settings)
    {
        Parameters = settings.Parameters;
    }

    public abstract T Execute(IScriptable scriptableObject);
    public abstract int GetArgumentCount();
    public abstract CommandSettings<T> Write();
}

public class CommandRandom : Command<float>
{
    public CommandRandom(CommandRandomSettings settings)
        : base(settings = settings == null ? new CommandRandomSettings() : settings)
    {
        if (settings == null)
        {
            settings = new CommandRandomSettings();
        }
    }

    public override float Execute()
    {
        return 0.0f;
    }

    public override int GetArgumentCount()
    {
        return 2;
    }

    public override CommandSettings<float> Write()
    {
        CommandRandomSettings settings = new CommandRandomSettings();

        settings.Parameters.AddRange(Parameters);

        return settings;
    }
}

public class CommandPosition : Command<object>
{
    public CommandPosition(CommandPositionSettings settings)
        : base(settings = settings == null ? new CommandPositionSettings() : settings)
    {
        if (settings == null)
        {
            settings = new CommandPositionSettings();
        }
    }

    public override object Execute(IScriptable scriptableObject)
    {
        Vector3 position = new Vector3();
        position.X = Parameters[0].Execute();
        position.Y = Parameters[1].Execute();
        position.Z = Parameters[2].Execute();

        scriptableObject.Position = position;
    }

    public override int GetArgumentCount()
    {
        return 3;
    }

    public override CommandSettings<object> Write()
    {
        CommandPositionSettings settings = new CommandPositionSettings();

        settings.Parameters.AddRange(Parameters);

        return settings;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately you cannot pass `void` as the type parameter in this case. In the above sample I used object instead. The `Execute(IScriptable scriptableObject)` method could simply return `null`.